# RaiseEvent("onchange")

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a winform and a `WebBrowser` control and I am changing an option in select HTML control.

```
webBrowser1.Document
    .GetElementsByTagName("select")[4]
    .GetElementsByTagName("option")[13]
    .SetAttribute("selected", "true");
```

Now it works and selects the required option, but it does not fire the `onchange` event. The select does not have an element id but it does have a class name.

I tried:

```
webBrowser1.Document
    .GetElementsByTagName("select")[4]
    .RaiseEvent("onchange");
```

and

```
webBrowser1.Document
    .GetElementsByTagName("select")[4]
    .GetElementsByTagName("option")[13]
    .RaiseEvent("onchange");
```

But in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried and sent a TAB key after selecting an option and it raised the onchange event.

```
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[4].Focus();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[4]
.GetElementsByTagName("option")[13].SetAttribute("selected", "true");
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

Everything is good now.

Answer (score 2):

try raising onChange event: e.g. RaiseEvent("onChange");

EDIT: it will be on the select element, not the option.

EDIT2:

```
var selectControlElement = webBrowser1.Document
    .GetElementsByTagName("select")[4];
selectControlElement.RaiseEvent("onChange");
```

Also its worth inspecting selectControlElement to see if it has any events.

Another option (untested by me)

```
object obj = selectControlElement.DomElement;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("onchange");
mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

Also try

```
selectControlElement.InvokeMember("onchange");
```

Comment: capital c, in onChange (although I thought it doesn't make a difference).

Comment: Apologies, I missclicked on the down arrow, didn't mean it, tried clicking the up arrow but it then goes to +1... don't know how to leave it at zero :S

Answer (score 1):

**Please see the code below for details.**

```
    void SetComboItem(string id, string value)
    {

        Forms.HtmlElement ddRouteSelected = wBrowser.Document.GetElementById(id);
        foreach (Forms.HtmlElement item in ddRouteSelected.Children)
        {
            if (item.InnerText != null && item.InnerText.ToLower().Equals(value.ToLower()))
            {
                item.SetAttribute("selected", "Selected");
                item.SetAttribute("value", value);
                ddRouteSelected.InvokeMember("onchange");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```