# C# Webbrowser element RaiseEvent issue

Tags: c#, jquery, events, browser

I am loading an external page into my Webbrowser. In this page there is a form an some components in the form. In my code, I want to trigger the "OnChange" event of the form. To do this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("choose_dept").RaiseEvent("onChange");
```

However, my code stops on this line due to the following error:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Why can't I fire the OnChange event of the form? Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

**Refer Following Code:**

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[4].Focus();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[4]
.GetElementsByTagName("option")[13].SetAttribute("selected", "true");
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

**Referance Link:**

[RaiseEvent("onchange")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044607/raiseeventonchange)

Comment: I have modified your code as follows:

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[1].Focus();            
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[1].GetElementsByTagName("input")[5].SetAttribute("checked", "checked");
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

Although it selects the 5th radio button, it doesn't trigger the event. There is a this.submit(); code in the onChange event. Ideally the page should be submitted but doesn't work.