# C# WebBrowser - How to Click on something without id

Tags: c#, html, .net, dom, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser and I want to click on something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:insertUnit($('#unit_input_axe'), 0)"></a>
```

This is my code but it is not working:

```
HtmlElementCollection links = _webB.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");

            foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
            {
                if (link.OuterHtml.Equals("<a href=" + "javascript:insertUnit($('#unit_input_axe'), 0)" + ">(0)</a>"))
                link.InvokeMember("click");
            }
```

I'm in need of help!
Thank you.

Comment: Is your problem connected with the fact that a link is not found or with the fact that it is found but not clicked? You can check it easily with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to add an "id" attribute to 'a' element and then find this element by its id property instead of searching for this by the whole href expression.

What is more in your current Equals expression there is (0) between opening and closing  tag which does not exist in the original expression.

Please also try to change

```
HtmlElementCollection links = _webB.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
```

To:

```
HtmlElementCollection links = _webB.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
```

Because so far as I remember GetElementsByTagName method is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try RaiseEvent("onclick").

Similar post: [RaiseEvent("onchange")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044607/raiseeventonchange)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how your equality comparison will ever be true. You are comparing:

```
<a href="javascript:insertUnit($('#unit_input_axe'), 0)">(0)</a>
```

with:

```
"<a href=" + "javascript:insertUnit($('#unit_input_axe'), 0)" + ">(0)</a>"
```

There are no inverted commas around the attribute value in the second. So it should, I think, be:

```
if (link.OuterHtml.Equals("<a href=\"javascript:insertUnit($('#unit_input_axe'), 0)\">(0)</a>"))
```

Leaving that aside, I have used `WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript` with some success for this. Since you appear to already know the specific function name and value you want to execute, you can avoid selecting the specific DOM item (A tag) and just execute the javascript directly.

There is a good looking guide here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/60924/Using-WebBrowser-Document-InvokeScript-to-mess-aro

Answer (score 0):

I think that changing from Tag "A" to "a" resolved this problem.
Here is my code that is  working . Thank you all for your help!

```
HtmlElementCollection links = _webB.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

            foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
            {
                if (link.OuterHtml.ToString().Contains("unit_input_axe"))
                    link.InvokeMember("click");
            }
```